# issue with Upload File with Primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces, upload, glassfish

I'm trying insert a download in my webApplication.

First of all the page which contains the form where there is the  is on

```
citizen/createparty.xhtml
```

And the folder where i'd like to upload the file is

```
partysymbols/ ..
```

Then i show to you the XHTML code:

```
<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <p:fileUpload value="#{partyCreationBean.file}" mode="simple" />
     <p:commandButton value="Submit" ajax="false" actionListener="#{partyCreationBean.upload}" />
```

Then the partyCreationBean

```
private UploadedFile file;

public UploadedFile getFile() {
    return file;
}

public void setFile(UploadedFile file) {
    this.file = file;
}
....
public void handleFileUpload() {
        File target = new File(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getApplication().get);
        System.out.println("handle file upload: " + file.getFileName());
        InputStream inputStream;
        try {
            inputStream = file.getInputstream();
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file.getFileName()
                );
        int read = 0;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

        while ((read = inputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
            out.write(bytes, 0, read);
        }
        inputStream.close();
        out.flush();
        out.close();
        System.out.println("done");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
public void upload() {
    if(file != null) {
        FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage("Succesful", file.getFileName() + " is uploaded.");
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, message);
        handleFileUpload();
    }
}
```

In my web.xml

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
        org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter
    </filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>thresholdSize</param-name>
        <param-value>51200</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>uploadDirectory</param-name>
        <param-value>partysymbols</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
```

The problem is that I reach the

System.out.println("done")

but I have no idea of where the file is uploaded.

then also, if i understood well the "uploadDirectory" parameter in the web.xml is not to set the directory where the file is setted.

I don't really understand how to do this stuff, also because it's first time that i work for a webapplication, and i use glassfish, and i have no idea about how the file system should work... I mean... i don't know where in reality are the pages and all the stuff... i just know where they are inside eclipse :/

Thankyou a lot in advance
Samuele

Answer (score 1):

I guess there is an error in your `handleFileUpload()` method:

The line

```
OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file.getFileName());
```

should probably be:

```
OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(target.getAbsolutePath() + file.getFileName());
```

This should also be the path where the file finally is stored, you can print it with:

```
System.out.println("Path: " + target.getAbsolutePath() + file.getFileName());
```

The line where the `target` var is initialized in your code seems to miss something but I guess it retrieves the `uploadDirectory` param from the `web.xml`.

You may have to set up an absolute path for the `uploadDirectory` param like `"c:\\tmp\\partysymbols"` (Windows) or `"/home/user/partysymbols"` (Unix) in your `web.xml`.

**See also:**

- [Where does p:fileUpload save my file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10666370/where-does-pfileupload-save-my-file)
- [j2ee primefaces fileupload file saving destination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4358493/j2ee-primefaces-fileupload-file-saving-destination)

Comment: thankyou... i managed to solve with: String path = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext()
             .getRealPath("/"); now is working